# Opendir function not showing what i want

Tags: php

I was trying to use this code to check the file's names i have in my directory.
But i just shows me the number "1" mutiple times. how to i show the folders and files names?

```
<php 
$folder = opendir("../../../www");

 while($entrada=readdir($folder)!=""){
 echo $entrada."<br>";
 }
 $folder = closedir($folder);
 ?>
```

I want t be able to show all folders and files and make then possible to acess through links, of course this is not the entire code but i cant continue if it dosent show me the names....

Comment: Just use correct example: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

Comment: The example actualy worked, i dont know exacly hwo but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one-liner style:

```
array_diff(scandir("../../../www"),array('.','..'));
```

Comment: for soem reason this one didnt work, it istill only shows me the number "1" multiple times.

Comment: I guess something's wrong with your folder path. Check it carefully.